How to make a transformation work with namespace prefixes? Adding it do xslt doesn't work
Here's the problem.
XMLDOM (Microsoft.XMLDOM object) doesn't indent XML. It's unreadable by human.
Previously, after making an XML document I would just run this tranformation
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:output method='xml' version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' indent='yes'/>
            <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>

Found it somewhere.
Then I would just take original XML object oXDoc, create this XML object oXsl with this XSLT transformation
instruction, and call transformNodeToObject, and make a 3rd object oRes that would be a already indented XML, and then save that 3rd object to disk or whatever.
oXDoc.transformNodeToObject(oXsl, oRes)
    oRes.Save(cXmlFile)

It worked fine, until documents with non-default namespaces appeared.
So, for example, XML like this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2">
<cbc:IssueDate>2024-11-07</cbc:IssueDate>
<cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
<cac:Party>
<cbc:EndpointID schemeID="1234">AB90000012345</cbc:EndpointID>
</cac:Party></cac:AccountingSupplierParty></Invoice>

No longer works, but I INCLUDED all namespaces in XSL, as I search for an answer, all seem to say that same thing.
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
        xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"        
        xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
            <xsl:output method='xml' version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' indent='yes'/>
            <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>

If I remove all prefixes in original XML Document, it works, it indents and includes all namespace bindings, but it's useless! I need to have ALL prefixes present because there are a LOT of common names between them, such as Name or ID, or whatever, or they would become ambiguous.
So what is the correct way to do it? How to make it indent the document AND keep all prefixes and not error out on me? I am copying the document as it is, only adding indentation. No actual transformation is necessary.
I tried this:
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>

<xsl:template match="@*|*:node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*:node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>

and
this
<xsl:template match="@*|:node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|:node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>

and even this
<xsl:template match="@*|:node()">
            <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|cbc:node()|cac:node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>

and many many many others.
Original code makes an error which just says something like "msxml3 :only a defaults namespace can have an empty URI." That's really odd. All namespaces are written in BOTH documents, so what gives???
And other tries just don't like the pattern and error says "invalid match pattern", "found :", "expected eof", and so on.
I also tried including

extension-element-prefixes="cbc cac #default"

into the xsl:stylesheet element with zero results.
UPDATE:
Well, this works FINALLY if I save xml before transformation to disk, then load it again into the same object and do the transformation.
Maybe there is something wrong with how elements are created? I just put the prefix with name together like this:
oEl = oMainEl.appendChild(oXDoc.createElement("cac:Party")).appendChild(oXDoc.createElement("cbc:EndpointID"))
    oEl.Text = "AB90000012345"
    oEl.setAttribute("schemeID", "1234")

Very odd. Maybe there needs to be some odd manipulation to be done
Maybe it needs to be replace with createNode, as answer suggests. Still not sure how to avoid writing full URL each time. It looks ugly in code, but when saved, with or without transformation, the full URL or URI are not showing, because they're already in root element. Thanks for help so far. Maybe indeed that XML DOM thing is too old.

I suspect that there is something wrong with the XML, not your XSLT. The simple identity transform (the original version) will work just fine when there are additional namespaces in the XML. Post the exact error message you are getting and maybe a more complete example of that XML.

Either the input XML is not what you show us here or you are using a non-conformant processor.

What does "no longer works" mean exactly, which error exactly do you get or in what way is the output you get different from the one you expect? And why do you use a legacy id like Microsoft.XMLDOM, MSXML 6 with its version specific program ids should be available on all supported Window OS versions.

XML I gave you also doesn't work with prefixes, short or long. The error is as I said: Only a default namespace can have an empty URI. (???) That's the point. If I just replace cbc:IssueDate with like  then it works fine. But it's of course useless. Maybe there is some new XML DOM stuff? I just don't want to rewrite all previously written stuff through the years with new XML processor. Only if there is a working version which understands prefixes and have all same code. I use VisualFoxPro, so .NET is useless here.

All these attempts you are making are useless. If it doesn't work with the original XSLT and the XML you posted here then your processor is the problem.

Another side note: you are likely to get a better-looking indentation if you add a <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> instruction to the top level of your stylesheet.

If I remember it right then, with MSXML, to properly create elements or nodes in general in a certain namespace, don't use createElement, use the proprietary createNode https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757901(v=vs.85) where you make sure you pass in the node type, the qualified name and the namespace URI of the node to create.
See the remarks on createElement in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757047(v=vs.85):

Creating an element with this method is the same as using createNode
where the type parameter value is NODE_ELEMENT and no namespace is
specified.
You cannot create a namespace-qualified element using the
createElement method. Regardless of whether a namespace prefix is
included in the tagName parameter*,* the namespaceURI property for the
new element node is set to an empty string, "". An element node
constructed as part of an XML document load operation will never have
both a prefix and an empty namespace Uniform Resource Identifier
(URI). You can only create a namespace-qualified element using the
createNode method of the DOMDocument object.


Indeed, I too suspect this is a DOM problem not an XSLT problem. DOM APIs allow you to create documents that are not namespace well formed (for example where element names have a prefix and no namespace URI), and XSLT isn't designed to cope with ill-formed input.

A side observation is that this is a typical case where you've got into a mess by using code that you don't understand ("found it somewhere"), and then you've read about a problem (need to declare namespaces in your XSLT) and without understanding that problem, and therefore without realising that it doesn't apply to your case, you've tried applying a solution and found that it makes no difference. To avoid this kind of time wasting, you need to read more deeply about the technologies you are using.

Oh, I know that. Everyone knows that. It's just so you don't always have time for every nook and cranny you can along. I just did that as an additional bit of work, I mostly do sql and forms stuff, not anything internet-related. But yeah, you're right.

And I can't upvote the answer, system won't let me, but I totally would. Who knew that old sofrware function libraries are THAT quirky and odd.

Part of the problem is that the W3C DOM in its first specification level 1 didn't have namespace aware methods and then in level 2 introduced namespace aware createElementNS. Microsoft earlier had found another way to have namespace awareness with createNode and never adapted to the W3C DOM in MSXML or .NET but in .NET preferred the more natural way to have overloads of createElement that allow providing a namespace. So part of the quirkyness is part of the overlapping history of designing a clean spec step wise from the W3C with companies like MS already designing/doing an implementation.
